# How to set the font on a Windows Calendar control?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using C++ and MFC and `CMonthCalCtrl`. There appears to be no way to set a font on a calendar control. Using the `SetFont()` function does nothing (it sends a `WM_SETFONT` message) and I cannot find any other functions. I'm using the control in a dialog and want to set the control to the same font as the dialog (which the user can set - so it's not the font specified in the template).

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Are you creating a font object and saving it for the life of the dialog?

Comment: Please show us your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to set a font of the CMonthCalCtrl: it has a member function `SetFont()`.

So in the dialog class you would have:

```
CMonthCalCtrl m_Calendar;
CFont m_Font;
```

And somewhere (in `OnInitDialog()`?), for example:

```
m_Font.CreateFont(20, 20, 0, 0, 700, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 
    DEFAULT_QUALITY, FF_DONTCARE, L"Impact");
m_Calendar.SetFont(&m_Font);
```

Comment: As I stated in my answer, that sure works for me :) Something must be wrong elsewhere in your code. For example, is your font defined in the local scope of the function? I mean - could it go out of scope and get destructed?